# related_part and identifying all images within a PPT presentation?

Tags: python-pptx

I had some code working a while back that looked roughly like this:

```
## "prs" is a handle to a PPTX presentation
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        for relpart in shape.part.related_parts.values():
            if isinstance(relpart, pptx.parts.image.ImagePart):
                ## do some stuff per image
```

This basically iterated through each slide, looking at each shape, and if said shape was of type "ImagePart" I would do some manipulations on that image.

It appears in more recent code the "related_parts" mechanism has gone away, which sort of makes sense as there's now `related_part(some_id)` -- but in my use case this breaks me because I was using the `values()` method against the dictionary-like object `related_parts`...  which now doesn't work.

Anyone have suggestions for a currently supported way of doing this?  Ultimately all I really need is something that will iterate through the slides so that I can get a mapping of slide numbers and shape_id's and partnames... the rest should all be consistent with my existing code.

Thanks  :)

Comment: Purely as a matter of interest (and because my code might do something like this one day)  what are you using this for?

Comment: I have coworkers who LOVE to dump gigantic uncompressed tiff or emf or png images into presentations, bloating them to obscene file sizes.  This is part of a script I'm working on to find the worst offenders in terms of file size and ultimately replace them with much smaller jpg's ...

Comment: Ah. OK. And they probably do it by pasting in the graphic. That usually does it. BTW they might like my md2pptx project where they can turn markdown into pptx, including embedding their images. I wrote it partly because I got sick of this "pasted graphic" bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `.rels` will function as an iterator, and the missing piece was `target_part`:

```
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if "Picture" in shape.name:
            for relpart in shape.part.rels:
                tgt = relpart.target_part
                if isinstance(tgt, pptx.parts.image.ImagePart):
                    img_bytes = sys.getsizeof(tgt.image.blob)
                    print(f"Slide {slide_num:>3} shape  {shape.shape_id:>4}, partname {tgt.partname}, dims {tgt.image.size}, {img_bytes} bytes")
```